# NSSpeechSynthesizer compact voices

Tags: xcode, text-to-speech, voiceover

I'm writing to ask you a question about NSSpeechSynthesizer. Really it works perfect for me, the only things I saw is strange (to me) is that the available voices are all the premium voices.

```
    NSArray* voices;
    voices = [NSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices];
```

When I print all voices in the array I can see, for instance, Silvia and Paolo, but not Silvia Compact and Paolo Compact.

For the italian language, unfortunately, the premium version have many bugs in their way of speaking that the compact voices haven't. So I'd like to be able to select the Compact version... does anyone of you know how can I make them available?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use availableVoices, and whenever a voice ends in ".premium" try replacing ".premium" with ".compact". That will only work with voices that the user has installed, but that should be no surprise for the user.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the using the identifier (Alice is the compact Italian voice):

```
let voiceId : String = "com.apple.ttsbundle.Alice-compact"

speechUtterL1 = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "dì qualcosa in italiano")
speechUtter.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: voiceId)
```

place the voice **after** the text, for I have seen issues when the voice parameter is set before the utterance.